# Dice roller having issues with second while loop

Tags: python

I'm a longterm lurker first time questioner. I'm trying to teach myself Python and while I've researched my question I couldn't find an answer. My below code runs if I remove the first While loop but currently it doesn't seem to enter the second while loop. I think I might be channelling my inner VBA which I use at work and this is only second time I've tried Python.
I've tried changing the first while so it isn't just while true and tried variants on the second while. 
The intent here is to investigate a dice pool mechanic for a game I'm thinking of and model rolling multiple D6s, 5-6 explode, 3+ successes and 1-2 failures. Ultimately I want it to run roll the dice return the dice list number of successes etc and then reset asking the user for number of dice to roll again.

```
import random
Scount = 0
Xcount = 0
Fcount = 0
rollcount = 0
cheat = 0
NoOfDice = 1
Dicelist = []
while True:
    print ("Input number of dice to roll")
    NoOfDice=input()
    while cheat<int(NoOfDice):
        rand = random.randint(1, 6)
        Dicelist.append(rand)
        if rand <= 4:
            cheat += 1
        if rand >= 3:
            Scount += 1
        if rand >= 2:
            Fcount += 1
        if rand <= 5:
            Xcount += 1
print (Dicelist)
print ("We rolled " + str(NoOfDice) + " you got " + str(Scount) + " number of succeses with " + str(Xcount) + " number of dice exploded with " + str(Fcount) + " dice failed")
```

Thank you all and appreciate your time!

Comment: it enters the second while loop for me. add a print() in there.

Comment: Great read: [How to debug small programs (#3)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/))

Comment: Do what is commented above, also possibly resetting base stats after.

Comment: Adi219 hit the nail on the head it is entering second loop it’s jusr not printing as I haven’t indented it. Many thanks Adi. My mouth dropped at the simplicity and thank you for pointing out the rookie mistake

Comment: Note that random.randint(1,6) will return a number from 0 to 5, not 1 to 6. So XCount will always be incremented. Similarly cheat, SCount and FCount may not be incremented as often (or as rarely) as you think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition for your first `while` loop is essentially going to always be `True`, meaning that it's an infinite loop.

Your second loop may not seem like it's running, but it definitely is (as long as you enter a number greater than 0).

The reason your program has no output is because your `print()` statements are after the infinite loop, so they'll never run. This is why your program runs as desired when you remove the infinite loop.

To fix this, just move your `print()` statements inside the first loop but at the end.

Note: If you want to get time to *read* what is being printed when you run the program, you should change the `print()`s to `input()`s as this will mean that the first loop only loops around after you've pressed `Enter`.

Additional Note: `random.randint(1, 6)` returns a value from 0 to 5 **not** from 1 to 6. Looking at your values in your `if` statements, you probably want to change code to:

```
rand = random.randint(1,6) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code could further be condensed using with just 2 if statements instead of 4.  Below is my proposed solution.  I wrapped it in a function but you don't have to.  I'll leave it for you think and decide how to escape the first "while" loop after the second while loop finished execution.

```
def rolldice ():
...     while True:
...         scount = 0
...         xcount = 0
...         fcount = 0
...         cheat = 0
...         NoOfDice = ''
...         DiceList = []
...         NoOfDice = input ('Number of dice to roll: ')
...         while cheat < int (NoOfDice):
...             rand = random.randint(1, 6)
...             DiceList.append (rand)
...             if rand <= 5:
...                 cheat += 1
...                 xcount += 1
...             if rand >= 2:
...                 fcount += 1
...                 scount += 1
...         print ('Dice List: ', DiceList)
...         print ('Number of dice rolled:', NoOfDice)
...         print ('Success Count: %d' % scount)
...         print ('Exploded Count: %d' % xcount)
...         print ('Failed Count: %d' % fcount)
... 
>>> rolldice()

Number of dice to roll: >? 3
Dice List:  [2, 3, 1]
Number of dice rolled: 3
Success Count: 2
Exploded Count: 3
Failed Count: 2

Number of dice to roll: >? 1
Dice List:  [5]
Number of dice rolled: 1
Success Count: 1
Exploded Count: 1
Failed Count: 1

Number of dice to roll:
```

Comment: rand <= 5. Is always true for random.randint(1, 6)!